# empty set confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\neg\left (\neg{\left (A\setminus A  \right )}\setminus A  \right )$

$A\setminus A $ is simply empty set and $\neg$ of that is again empty set. Empty set $\setminus$ A is empty set or? But every empty set is included in every set?

I am confused when it comes to this..

Comment: Does your $\neg$ mean complement ?

Comment: Does $\neg{\left (A\setminus A  \right )}\setminus A $ mean $\neg \left(\left (A\setminus A  \right )\setminus A \right)$ or $\left(\neg\left (A\setminus A  \right )\right)\setminus A $ ?

Comment: $\emptyset \setminus X = \{x~:~x\in \emptyset \wedge x\notin X\} = \emptyset$ for all $X$ since clearly no $x$ satisfies the first part of the condition $x\in \emptyset$, regardless of the second part of the condition.

Comment: Why would you think $\lnot \emptyset$ would be an empty set?  $\lnot \emptyset$ would be everything not in the empty set.... which would be EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'negation' you mean complement, then the 'negation' of the empty set is not the empty set, but the universal set ... or at least: the set of all things you are talking about: the Universe of Discourse. If we call that $U$, we get:

$((A\setminus A)'\setminus A)'=(\emptyset'\setminus A)'=(U\setminus A)'=A$

To go into that last step a little more:

$A \setminus B$ is the same as $A \cap B'$, and so:

$(U\setminus A)'=(U \cap A')'=U' \cup A''=\emptyset \cup A = A$

Comment: Well, if you remove everything in $A$ from the universal set, you get the set of all things that are not in $A$ ... but if you take the complement of that, you get everything that is in $A$ (and nothing else) ... so that's exactly $A$.  In short: $(U \setminus A)'=A$

Answer (score 1):

The emptyset is subset of every set $ E $ because you cannot find an element which is in the emptyset and not in the set $ E$.
$$\text{ Proof}$$

Let $ x$ be an arbitrary element,

$ p, q$  the propositions
 $$p \;\; : \; x\notin \emptyset$$
and
$$ q \;\; : \;\; x\in E.$$

By the emptyset Axiom, the proposition $ p$ is always true.

By the argument of Addition,

the proposition $  p \vee q$ is also true,
and by material implication,

$$\neg p \;\; \implies q \;\; \text{ is true}$$
or
$$x\in \emptyset\;\; \implies \;\;  x\in E$$
thus
$$\emptyset \;\; \subset\;\;  E$$

Answer (score 1):

Just use the laws of operator precedence to evaluate the result of each binary or unary operation in the proper order:
\begin{align}
A\setminus A&=\emptyset\\
\therefore \neg(A\setminus A)&=\Omega\ \ \ \text{(universal set)}\\
\therefore \neg(A\setminus A)\setminus A&=\Omega\setminus A\\
\therefore \neg(\neg(A\setminus A)\setminus A)&=\neg(\Omega\setminus A)\\
&=\neg\Omega\cup A\ \ \ \text{(De Morgan)}\\
&=\emptyset\cup A\\
&=A
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$A$ = everthing that is is $A$.

$A\setminus A$ = everything in $A$ that is not in $A$ = nothing = $\emptyset$

$\lnot(A\setminus A) = \lnot \emptyset$ = everything that is not in the emptyset = everything = The Universal Set. I'll call it $U$.

$\lnot(A\setminus A) \setminus A$ = $U\setminus A$= everything in the universal Set that is not in $A$ = $\lnot A$.

$\lnot (\lnot A\setminus A)\setminus A) =\lnot(\lnot A)$= everything that is not not in A = everything that is in $A$ = $A$.

.....

Or $\neg\left (\neg{\left (A\setminus A  \right )}\setminus A  \right )=$

$\{x| x\not \in  (\neg{\left (A\setminus A  \right )}\setminus A   )\}=$

$\{x|x\not \in \{x\in \neg(A\setminus A)|x\not \in A\}\}=$

$\{x|x\not \in \{x\not \in (A\setminus A)|x\not \in A\}\}=$

$\{x|x\not \in \{x\not \in \{x \in A|x\not \in A\}|x\not \in A\}\}=$

$\{x|x\not\in\{x\not \in \emptyset|x\not \in A\}\}=$

$\{x|x\not \in \{x\not \in A\}\}=$

$\{x|x \in A\}=$

$A$